# how to search nearby website development company using google api

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-places-api

I want to list of all the nearby website development companies and I have used "website_designer" as the search keyword but it is not working. If I search for restaurant by using "restaurant" as the search keyword then itworks fine. If anybody knows the solution please help me.
On the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks. When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image_src = "images/";
    var map; // 
    var infowindow;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var PlaceArray = ["website_designer"]; // search keyword
    var PlaceCounter = 0;
    function initialize() {
        "use strict";
        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(25.448677, 81.834382); //(latitude,longitude)
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMapNearestPlaces'), {
        center: pyrmont,
        zoom: 14,
        icon: 'images/map_marker.png',
        scrollwheel: false,
        rankby: 'distance',
        styles: [{
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#00c775"
            }]
        }, 
        {
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "gamma": 0.01
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -31
            },
            {
                "lightness": -33
            },
            {
                "weight": 2
            },
            {
                "gamma": 0.8
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels.icon",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "on"
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }, 
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "lightness": 30
            }, 
            {
                "saturation": 30
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "saturation": 20
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi.park",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "lightness": 20
            }, 
            {
                "saturation": -20
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "lightness": 10
            }, 
            {
                "saturation": -30
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "saturation": 25
            }, 
            {
                "lightness": 25
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "transit",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
                "lightness": "0"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "color": "#00c775"
            },
            {
                "gamma": "1"
            },
            {
                "weight": "1"
            }]
        }, 
        {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }]
   });
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pyrmont,
        icon: 'images/map_marker.png'
   });
   marker.setMap(map);
   var request = {
        location: pyrmont,
        radius: 5000,
        types: ["website_designer"]
    };
   infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
   service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}
function callback(results, status) {
    "use strict";
   if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    }
}
function createMarker(place) {
   "use strict";
   var place_icon;
   place_icon = "images/map-icons/" + place.types['0'] + ".png";
   var PlaceType = place.types['0'];
   if (jQuery.inArray(PlaceType, PlaceArray) == -1) {
        return;
   }
   PlaceArray = jQuery.grep(PlaceArray, function(value) {
        return value = PlaceType;
   });
   var Distance = distance(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng());
    //console.log(place.geometry.location.lat(),place.geometry.location.lng())
   function distance(latitude2, longitude2) {
        var lat1 = "25.448677";
        var lon1 = "81.834382";  
        var lat2 = latitude2;
        var lon2 = longitude2;
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180;
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180;
        var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1 / 180;
        var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2 / 180;
        var theta = lon1 - lon2;
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        dist = dist * 1.609344;
        return Math.round(dist * 100) / 100;
    }
    jQuery("#near-by-place-detail").append("<ul><li class='left'><p><b>" + PlaceType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + PlaceType.substr(1) + "</b></p><span>" + place.name + "</span></li><li class='right'><label>" + Distance + " Km</label></li></ul>");
   var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        icon: place_icon,
   });
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
   });
   bounds.extend(marker.position);
   //now fit the map to the newly inclusive bounds
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   //(optional) restore the zoom level after the map is done scaling
   var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
        map.setZoom(12);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
   });
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});   
</script>
<section class="near_by_places">
   <div class="container">
      <h2>Near By Places</h2>
      <div class="row">
         <div id="near-by-place-detail" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
         <div class="near-by-place-map col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
            <div id="googleMapNearestPlaces" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: try with website%20designer instead of website_designer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no `type` related with the `website development` or the `website designer`. You can see all the supported types here.
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types

You can use **Text Search Requests** instead as follow.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=website_companies_in_newyork&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

in the `query` you can specify any search query and Google will provide you a list of places.

You can either search for something like this as well.

```
query = shoe stores near New York
```

Read more about here
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: ok, sir is there any alternate of it like can we add our own keyword in google  API

Comment: @AbhayjeetSingh I updated the answer. If it helps you please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: sorry sir, I have seen all these stuffs

Comment: Actually, my goal is to search nonpopular companies or firms

Comment: is API key is necessary?

Comment: Yes. it should be provided.

Comment: In Google search when you type _Restaurants near me_ Google will show you some places near you. Those kind of information can be gathered through these APIs.

Comment: Hello Sir, how to use the api as I have used different url and if change url it doesn't work

Comment: You should first have a Api Key